# Is it permissible to work in a financial brokerage house as a marketing and sales representative?

Tags: finance

Before going to start job in a financial brokerage house I want to confirm that is it permissible or not. In a financial brokerage house I have been selected as a business development executive in this designation I will have to serve company in sales and marketing.
I got acknowledged that the source of make money for a financial brokerage and financial services provider is commission.